# Is there any way to add a specific category and flag an email in VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook-2007

I normally go through my email and flag anything for follow up and categorize for:

1. Phone Call
2. Email
3. Talk To
4. Setup meeting

Is there any way in a Outlook VBA macro, I can (in a single macro), both flag an item for follow and set one of the above categories on it?

Comment: Can you add which version of Outlook you're using. The object model changed significantly between 2003 and 2007

Comment: Yes, it's very easy to do. Are you looking for a button, plus a drop down, set to call the macro.

Comment: http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2007/03/19/outlook-tags/

You might find the comments to this post useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer . .listed below . . .

```
Private Sub TagArchived1(category As String)

    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objInspector As Outlook.Inspector

    Dim strDateTime As String

    ' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    ' The ActiveInspector is the currently open item.
    Set objExplorer = objOutlook.ActiveExplorer

    ' Check and see if anything is open.
    If Not objExplorer Is Nothing Then
        ' Get the current item.
        Dim arySelection As Object
        Set arySelection = objExplorer.Selection

        For x = 1 To arySelection.Count
            Dim m As MailItem
            Set m = arySelection.Item(x)
            m.Categories = category
            m.FlagStatus = olFlagMarked
            m.FlagIcon = 6
            m.Save
        Next x

    Else
        ' Show error message with only the OK button.
        MsgBox "No explorer is open", vbOKOnly
    End If

    ' Set all objects equal to Nothing to destroy them and
    ' release the memory and resources they take.
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set objExplorer = Nothing
End Sub
```